# How to add jupyter to rocker image?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new to `docker` and I'm trying to add `jupyter` and `python` to my `docker` image based on [`Rocker`](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned/blob/master/rstudio/3.5.2/Dockerfile) (I want to have both `python` and `R`). I was able to install `python3`and `jupyter` with the dependencies. Image was created successfully. After running container I have access to `RStudio server` on port `7878`, but unfortunately on port `8888` `jupyter` is not working.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this :

```
FROM rocker/rstudio:3.5.0

# Basic dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
      libssl-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      vim \
      nano \
      libxml2 \
      libxml2-dev \
      curl \
      gnupg2 \
      build-essential libssl-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      ssh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Install python3 and pip3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential

# Install jupyter
RUN pip3 install jupyter

EXPOSE 8888
RUN mkdir /notebooks
CMD jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --port 8888 /notebooks

CMD ["/init"]
```

Build and run:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t user/my_docer:1.0 .
docker run -d --name my_docker -p 8787:8787 -p 8888:8888 -v `pwd`:/mnt user/my_docer:1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use several `CMD` instructions - the second one overrides the first. If you need several processes to run in your container, **which is treated as a bad practice**, better use software like `supervisord`.

Another option is putting all stuff in a single `CMD` instruction like

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "'jupiter blahblah && /init'"]
```